# Ending the session and cookie of a particular user

Tags: php

As the admin of a site, when I delete a user, how do I delete all session and cookies stored in that user browser??

**deleteuser.php**

```
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=:uid");
$stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
$stmt->execute();
```

When a user logs in or register, a session and cookie is created

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;

setcookie(
    'remember',
     $selector.':'.base64_encode($authenticator),
     time()+(86400 * 90),
     '/',
     false
);
```

And when a user logs out, this is the code I use.

**logout.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION);
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
unset($_COOKIE['remember']);
setcookie('remember', '', time() - 3600, '/'); // empty value and old 
timestamp
}
session_destroy();
```

This works fine for current logged in user...

but as the admin, I want be able to delete the session/cookies of any user since i can get the user id(uid) in **deleteuser.php**.

Comment: You can't directly affect what's in the users browser from the admin. You need to have something in place when a user does a request, like checking if the user is valid. Example. The user requests a page, you then check if they have an active session. If yes, check the database and see if the user is deleted or not. If they are deleted, then just run the code from your logout.php.

Comment: How do I check if a user has been deleted when the records aren't in the database anymore? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You won't find anything when you search for the user? Store the user id in the session and get the user data on each request based on the user id. If the id doesn't match anything in the database, they have been deleted and you can log out the user.